# MongoDB query to add new element in array or update the element if one of attributes is not changed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have such document

```
{
    "_id" : "N4H7gYQwNXwTiEe62",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-07T20:18:59.144Z"),
    "title" : "Two roads",
    "userId" : "CnugxoBWs4ox6vG2k",
    "awards" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "suggested",
            "place" : 1.0,
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-23T20:33:58.885Z")
        },
        {
            "type" : "voted",
            "place" : 3,
            "addedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-23T20:33:58.885Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to write a query which add a new element in "awards" if "type" is not exists (fexample: new type "removed"), or update if type exists already as "suggested" or "voted". I need to update "place" and "addedAt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query to add a new element in "awards" if particular "type" does not exist (fexample: new type "removed"):

```
db.collection.update({
  "awards.type": {
    "$ne": "removed"
  }
},
{
  "$addToSet": {
    "awards": {
      type: "removed"
    }
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o4zMCOsl8Kq)

Query to update if type exists already as "suggested":

```
db.collection.update({
  "awards.type": "suggested"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "awards.$.place": 0 /* replace 0 with your value */
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GdpzH8IFlMX)

If you want to update multiple documents, make sure you add `multi:true`